# nao encontro classpath do jaspersoft studio

Tags: java, jasper-reports

boa noite

alguem sabe como configuro o classpath do jasperstudio para eu conseguir testa os relatorios baseado em beandatasource? No ireport tinha opcao mas nesse nao consigo achaar.